# Maximum Value of a Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$. What is the most likely outcome of $X$?

Please help me solve this exercise.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Giulio Off-topic, please read the question.

Comment: @Sophie Which words do you fail to understand in this? Because if you understand them all, it is difficult to imagine where you are stuck...

Comment: I did find the solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge 0$, $$P(X=n)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$ In particular $P(X=n)=\frac{\lambda}{n}P(X=n-1)$. So the sequence $P(X=n)$ grows for a while, then it's eventualy decreasing. And the reason/measure of this is...

Comment: Can you give more explanation? I still don't understand.

Comment: @Sophie Can you remind me of three ways to numerically check if a sequence $a_n$ is decreasing?

Comment: $\lambda > 0$ so $\lambda / n > 1$ for $n < \lambda$, but then growing $n$ clearly $n^* > \lambda$ for some $\lambda$ hence the increment is smaller and smaller.

Comment: A more detailed explanation for the ones who didn't get it: While $n < \lambda$, the series is increasing because $P(X=n) = \frac{\lambda}{n} P(X=n-1) > P(X=n-1)$. But when $n$ gets bigger than $\lambda$, the series decreases since $P(X=n) = \frac{\lambda}{n} P(X=n-1) < P(X=n-1)$. The maximum $P(X=n)$ is  therefor at $n \approx \lambda$. More precisely it is maximal at the biggest whole integer smaller or equal $\lambda$.